# Different boundaries of a set, its closure und interior in R

Tags: general-topology

Denoting $\overline A$ as closure of A, $A°$ as interior of A.

I've proven that in a general topology (X,O), following is true:

$\partial\overline A \subseteq \partial A$ and $\partial A° \subseteq A$, where $A \subseteq X $ and $\partial A$ is defined as $\partial A := \overline A / A° $.

Now I should consider the generell topology in $R$ and find a subset $B\subseteq R$ such that the boundaries $\partial\overline A, \partial A° $ and $ \partial A $ each are different.

I've tried considering $B=[a,b], B=]a,b[, B = ]a,b], B=[a,b] \cup\{c\} $ but none of these are satisfying the condition..

I'm relatively new to topologies..hopefully you have an idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You'll need a set of which the closure is larger than the set, and the interior is smaller than the set. Three of your candidates don't satisfy this criterion.
- Furthermore, note that $\partial \mathring{A} = \overline{\mathring{A}} \setminus \mathring{\mathring{A}} = \overline{\mathring{A}} \setminus {\mathring{A}}$ (taking the interior of an open set yields the open set!). So we need a set where $\overline{\mathring{A}} \neq \overline{A}$, otherwise simply $\partial \mathring{A} = \partial A$.

Note that your idea of adding a 'separate' singleton ($\{c\}$) helps in this respect. Let $A = [a,b] \cup \{c\}$, as in your example. $c$ lies in the closure of $A$, but is gone when we take $\overline{\mathring{A}}$!

- Note that $\partial \overline{A} = \overline{\overline{A}} \setminus \mathring{\overline{A}} = \overline{A} \setminus \mathring{\overline{A}}$. So we need a set where $\mathring{\overline{A}} \neq \mathring{A}$, as otherwise $\partial A = \partial \overline{A}$.

The interior of the closure of the set can be larger than the interior of the set. This holds for $A = [0,1) \cup (1,2]$, as here $1$ lies in the interior of the closure, but not in the interior.

Now try combining those ideas.

Comment: Well, adding together we have: $ A =[a,b) \cup (b,c] \cup \{d\} $ and after applying all the things, we fulfill the required condition, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Can you think of a subset of $[0,1]$ that has empty interior and is dense in $[0,1]$?

Comment: Are u hinting to something like $A$ = $\mathbb{Q}$ ? If i'm correct, then $\overline A$ = $\mathbb{R}$ (Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in  $\mathbb{R}$), $A°$ = empty set, ($\overline A$)° = $\mathbb{R}$ and $\overline (A°)$ = empty set, which would satisfy the conditions?

Comment: Nvm that. U surely meant $A = \mathbb(Q) \cap [0,1]$, right?

Comment: @Mathpiano: I was indeed thinking of $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb{R}$ under the usual topology. 
$\\$

Consider, $A= (0,1)\cup(1,2)\cup\{3\}$. 
Then $\overline{A}= [0,2] \cup\{3\}$ and $A^°=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$.
$\\$

$\partial A= \{ 0,1,2, 3\} \\$

$\partial \overline{A}= \{ 0,2,3\} \\$

$\partial A^°= \{ 0,1,2\} \\$

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!